# How do I keep users input after closing modal in the same page without reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to keep the data that the user decided in the checkbox of the modal and send it with the checkbox decision outisde of the modal without leaving the page or reloading.

If the user decides to check the checkbox within the modal how do I keep that data when I press continue to then wait for the submit button to send tha values of all the checkboxes.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option" />
      <input type="submit" value="continue" />
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="value" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not think of a modal as an entity separate from your page. A modal is *just a normal div* on your page, but it is positioned centered and overtop of other things. But it's just a regular div and you can read the values of elements in the modal at any time, even when it's invisible.

The values in the modal's checkbox are still available, just as they would be if they were in a different div. If your form is in the modal, then they are still part of the form. If the form is outside the modal, then you want to use javascript/jQuery *at any time* to read that checkbox and influence your form.

Here is an example where the form is outside the modal, and javascript updates the value of a form field when the modal is closed.

```js
$('#myModal').modal('hide');

$('button').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$('#myCB').change(function(){
    $('form input[name=inFormCB]').val( $(this).prop('checked') );
});
```

```css
form{width:100%;padding:30px;background:wheat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>INSTRUCTIONS: Open modal. Check/Uncheck the checkbox. Close modal. Observe result.</p>
<button>Open Modal</button>

<form>
  Value of checkbox myCB:<br>
  <input type="text" name="inFormCB" />
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        <input id="myCB" type="checkbox" /> Got It
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must make a css of that text Option : to Focus

Comment: will that keep the value of the current checkbox after user manipulation?